# I am learning the nextjs and cannot get to creating the app in the repository I choose. It spills out ENOENT error code, a system call and path

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Everytime I try to create a nextjs app, my compiler gives the following message:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Kong\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Kong\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Kindly assist.

I ran the `npx create-next-app@latest ./` command, and expected the app to be created in the directory I selected but it spews an error and I cannot get past the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're adding a path to the `command`.

Just access the directory you want to create the app and run:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

Or if you really want to add an specific path you can use the non-interactive `command` of [create-next-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-next-app):

```
create-next-app <project-directory> [options]
```